How to get the definition of a MATERIALIZED VIEW in Snowflake and use it as a subquery or CTE?
I need to create a subquery or CTE where I get the name of all my materialized view and its definition (how it was created, I mean its DDL). My main purpose is to know where the materialized view is getting the data from (That's why I want the DDL)
I know that I can get the information I need from the following query:
SHOW MATERIALIZED VIEWS IN DATABASE DB_NAME;

That query will give me all the Materialized Views of the database I need, which is great but that information I can not use it in a subquery or CTE.
To share a simple example of what I need you can try this query:
SELECT database_name, schema_name, name, text
FROM (SHOW MATERIALIZED VIEWS IN DATABASE DB_NAME);

And also, this other query:
WITH
CTE AS (
SHOW MATERIALIZED VIEWS IN DATABASE DB_NAME)
SELECT database_name, schema_name, name, TEXT
FROM CTE;

And both of them give back syntax errors, which makes me understand that the SHOW statement is not available to use in a subquery.
Do you know any way where I can get the DDL of my materialized views in a subquery?

Not sure if this helps but it's quite similar but that OP wanted the DDL for tables, not views.

RESULT_SCAN can help here. For any SHOW query, you can immediately follow up with a second query of the results. For example,
SHOW MATERIALIZED VIEWS IN DATABASE DB_NAME;
SELECT "database_name", "schema_name", "name", "text" FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));

